# sap.m.PlanningCalendar want to disable dates according to start date and end date

Tags: sapui5

I'm new for SAPUI5, I'm using plan calendar for assigning some schedule for employee.Though i'm able to do it but if i want to update already scheduled task then in the popup small calendar gets opened. In that calendar i want to provide validation for start date and end date as if user selects start date then automatically for end date calendar dates less than start date should get disabled.

Sharing screen shot of planning calendar and it's reference documentation.

[image: update scheduled dates]

[Planning calendar documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.PlanningCalendarModifyAppointments/preview)

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't u use the '**change**' event of [sap.m.DatePicker](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.DatePicker/controlProperties)? If the value changes, set the '**minDate**' property of the datepicker.

**Fragment**

```
<DatePicker id="idStartDate" change="onChangeStartDate"/>
<DatePicker id="idEndDate" change="onChangeEndDate"/>
```

**Controller** - don't forget to define `sap.ui.core.Fragment` in controller definiton

```
  // don't forget to define Fragment in controller
   onChangeStartDate: function(){ 
        var startDate = Fragment.byId("fragId, "idStartDate").getDateValue();
        Fragment.byId("fragId, "idEndDate").setMinDate(startDate);
    },

   onChangeEndDate: function(){ 
        var endDate = Fragment.byId("fragId, "idEndDate").getDateValue();
        Fragment.byId("fragId, "idStartDate").setMaxDate(endDate);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Matthijs..! Can you add one more condition for end date also? so that i can accept your ans.it will be helpful for other users also.

Comment: Do you mean this one?

Comment: I mean like onChangeStartDate create another fun- onChangeEndDate, and there you can mention endDate  >= startDate always.

Answer (score 0):

Just use binding. I will assume your first input field is bound against `{StartDate}` and the second against `{EndDate}`

Then you can bind the second DatePickers minDate Property to `{StartDate}` like this:

```
    <DatePicker dateValue="{StartDate}"/> 
    <DatePicker dateValue="{EndDate}" minDate="{StartDate}"/>
```

(BTW: you could use `sap.ui.unified.Calendar` for Date Range Selections: [Explored Example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.unified.sample.CalendarSingleIntervalSelection/preview))